# cannot find ProccessingDuplicate property of stimulsoft Report

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

In design time of the `stimulsoft report` tools,
I cannot find `ProccessingDuplicate` property for `Text` Object.
Is there any problem with my PropertyGrid ?  Like "Show Advance Properties" or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the interface complexity style is choosen when you first start the designer.
Of course you could switch the interface at will afterwards.

Right click on the Properties panel and select the interface `Professional` or `Standard`
The property `ProcessingDuplicate` is invisible when the interface is in `Basic mode`